# How to fix java keyPressed Lag/Late events

Tags: java, swing, keypress, lag, event-listener

I am sort of a noob at this but have attempted to create my own mario game.
It's going well but I need a variable called distanceTraveled to be determined

It isn't reliable at all, when I hold the arrow key numbers go faster than if I was to tap them.

Here are my codes(Everything is commented on the right):

.

frame.java

```
package EvilMario;                                                                               //Include this class in the EvilMario game package

import javax.swing.JFrame;                                                                       //Import the JFrame

public class frame {                                                                             //Run this class to run the game
    public static void main(String[] args) {                                                     //The first method called by java
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("EvilMario v.1.0.0 by Max Mastalerz");                         //Create JFrame called frame

        frame.getContentPane().add(new board());                                                 //Go to board class
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                                    //Make frame close on X click
        frame.setSize(600,413);                                                                  //Set the frame size to the size of the background
        frame.setVisible(true);                                                                  //Make the frame visible
        frame.setResizable(false);                                                               //Make sure the user can't resize the frame
    }
}
```

player.java

```
package EvilMario;                                                                               //Include this class in the EvilMario game package

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class player {
    int x, dx, y, nx, nx2, distanceTraveled;                                                     //x coordinate,change in x coordinate,y coordinate,1st rep bg,2nd rep bg,dist traveled
    Image player;                                                                                //The player variable
    ImageIcon playerFacingLeft = new     ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/MarioLeft.png");  //Image for player while he is     turning left
    ImageIcon playerFacingRight = new     ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/MarioRight.png");//Image for player while he is turning right

        public player() {
            player = playerFacingRight.getImage();                                           //Give the player the image
            x = 75;                                                                          //The original x position of the player
            y = 265;                                                                         //The original y position of the player
            nx = -0;                                                                         //Repeating background 1
            nx2 = -575;                                                                      //Repeating background 2
            distanceTraveled = 0;
        }

        public void move() {
            if(x>0 && x<300) {                                                               //If the player is within the moving area
                x = x+dx;                                                                    //The x position is updated to become itself+the amount you moved
                nx = nx+dx;                                                                  //Place the repeating background at regular speed
                nx2 = nx2+dx;                                                                //Place the repeating background at regular speed
            }
            if(x==0) {                                                                       //If the player has reached he very left side of the screen(0px)
                x=1;                                                                         //Move him up a pixel so he can move again

                nx = nx+(dx*(int)0.5);                                                       //Place the background at a slower speed since Mario stops moving
                nx2 = nx2+(dx*(int)0.5);                                                     //Place the background at a slower speed since Mario stops moving

            }
            if(x==300) {                                                                     //If the player has reached the center of the screen(300px)
                x=299;                                                                       //Move him down a pixel so he can move again
                nx = nx+(dx*(int)0.5);                                                       //Place the background at a slower speed since Mario stops moving
                nx2 = nx2+(dx*(int)0.5);                                                     //Place the background at a slower speed since Mario stops moving
            }
            System.out.println(distanceTraveled);
        }

        public int   getX()     { return x;      }                                           //This method will return the x.      Is used by other classes
        public int   getY()     { return y;      }                                           //This method will return the y.      Is used by other classes
        public Image getImage() { return player; }                                           //This method will return the player. Is used by other classes

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {                                                 //Called from the board class, the argument is whatever key was pressed
            int key = e.getKeyCode();                                                        //The key originally sent from the board class

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {                                                    //If the key sent was LEFT
                player = playerFacingLeft.getImage();                                        //Make the player face leftwards
                dx = -1;
                distanceTraveled--;
            }

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {                                                   //If the key sent was RIGHT
                player = playerFacingRight.getImage();                                       //Make the player face rightwards
                dx = 1;                                                                      //Move right
                distanceTraveled++;
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {                                                //Called from the board class, the argument is whatever key was released
             int key = e.getKeyCode();                                                        //The key originally sent from the board class

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)                          //If the left or right key was released
                dx = 0;                                                                      //Stop moving
        }
}
```

board.java

```
package EvilMario;                                                                           //Include this class in the EvilMario game package

import java.awt.*;                                                                           //Imported to allow use of Image
import java.awt.event.*;                                                                     //Imported to allow use of ActionListener

import javax.swing.*;

public class board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
player p;                                                                                        //Instance of player class
Image background;                                                                            //The background variable
Timer time;                                                                                  //A timer

    public board() {
        p = new player();                                                                    //Start running player class
        addKeyListener(new AL());                                                            //Listen for keys
        setFocusable(true);                                                                  //Allows movement                      
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/EvilMario_Background.png");  //Image for background
        background = i.getImage();                                                           //Give the background the image
        time = new Timer(7,this);                                                            //Timer set to update "this" class every 5 milliseconds
        time.start();                                                                        //Actually start the timer
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        p.move();                                                                            //Call the move method from the player class
        repaint();                                                                           //Repaint
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {                                                          //Graphics method
        super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;                                                 //casts 2d graphics(or however you would explain it)

            g2d.drawImage(background, -p.nx, 0, null);                                       //Draw the background image
            g2d.drawImage(background, -p.nx2, 0, null);                                      //Draw the background image

            if(-p.nx<-575)                                                                   //If going forwards
                p.nx=-575;                                                                   //Start placing forwards every 575px in front on the last one
            else if(-p.nx>575)                                                               //If going backwards
                p.nx=575;                                                                    //Start placing backwards every 575px behind the last one

             if(-p.nx2<-575)                                                                  //If going forwards
                p.nx2=-575;                                                                  //Start placing forwards every 575px in front on the last one
            else if(-p.nx2>575)                                                              //If going backwards
                p.nx2=575;                                                                   //Start placing backgrounds every 575px behind the last one

            g2d.drawImage(p.getImage(), p.getX(), p.getY(), null);                           //Draw the player at the position he is currently(Coordinate values taken from player class)
        }

    private class AL extends KeyAdapter {                                                    //Action Listener extends key adapter
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {                                                 //On key press
            p.keyPressed(e);                                                                 //Send whatever key was pressed  TO the keyPressed  method in the player class
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {                                                //On key release
            p.keyReleased(e);                                                                //Send whatever key was released TO the keyReleased method in the player class
        }
    }
}
```

### If you wish to test this game yourself, you will need these three images

EvilMario_Background.png

[image: EvilMario_Background.png]

MarioLeft.png

[image: MarioLeft.png]

MarioRight.png

[image: MarioRight.png]

Also change the directories
I've been trying too many things with this and have not come up with anything, If you figure this out I will be forever grateful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then trying to calculate the distance in the key event handlers, calculate it within the `move` method.  This would be based on the value of `dx` been either greater or less then `0`

- You really should be using `paintComponent` by convention, rather the `paint`
- You should consider using the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as it solves many of the problems associated with the `KeyListener`
- I would rely more on the actual `width` and `height` properties of the `JPanel` rather then "magic" numbers.  The problem here is different platforms and look and feels have different frame border sizes, which will effect these values.  Consider overriding `getPreferredSize` in the `board` to return the preferred size of the gaming canvas.  Then you can use `pack` on the frame instead.
- Call `setResizable` before trying to size or show the window, this will change the size of the frame border and change the size of the viewable area...
- A `7` millisecond delay is something like 143fps...I seriously doubt you really need that kind of refresh rate.  `40` milliseconds is 25fps and I dare you do tell the difference, event 60fps is only `16` milliseconds.  Don't change the speed of your refresh rate, change the speed of your delta values to alter the speed of the game...just saying ;)

Comment: "40 milliseconds is 25fps and I dare you do tell the difference" What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that the difference between 143ps and 25fps would be unnoticeable give your current requirements, most monitors refresh at about 25mzh anyway.  You're `Timer` is updating to much which could actually cause a issues in it's ability to process changes to the state of the game between refreshes. I've had 10, 000 animated objects paint on a screen @ 25fps without issues ;)

Comment: "most monitors refresh at about 25mzh anyway" If you mean 25 Hz, you're *very* wrong: the lowest refresh rate you'll find on most computers today is 50 Hz, and monitors that can refresh at 100 Hz and higher are becoming common.

Comment: "You're `Timer` is updating to much which could actually cause a issues in it's ability to process changes to the state of the game between refreshes." What are you talking about? Overhead? Concurrency?

Comment: Pretty much. Your timer is going to starve other threads, but it's also going to flood the EDT with a lot of events that it needs to process, when is going to cause it a lot of stress, especially the longer it runs. I appear to be getting my numbers mixed around with the screens...it's late, 2 year old not sleeping make brain go mush...

Comment: @MadProgrammer You sir are a legend. If you where a girl, I would marry you, but seriously... You have no idea how hard I tried to fix this, I think I stayed up til 5, and slept 1 hour.